# Byte to String to byte conversion puzzling error

Tags: c#, string, byte, getstring

Could anyone please help spot the error? Here's the code:

```
   byte[] oriBytes = { 0xB0, 0x2D };                       // oriBytes -> 0xB0, 0x2D
   string oriInStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(oriBytes);   // oriInStr ->   "?-"
   oriBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(oriInStr);           // oriBytes -> 0x3F, 0x2D
```

I can't get back the original bytes values of `0xB0`, `0x2D`.

Comment: Why are you decoding using ASCII? Is your input restricted to ASCII?

Comment: Use `Encoding.Default`, this implements the codepage as used in your OS

Comment: I've just solved it. just use Encoding.Unicode instead of ASCII. I work with every bit of a byte for my electronic hardware, ARM and PIC..

Comment: Just make sure you are aware of input encoding while decoding otherwise you will end up in similar errors.

Answer (score 8):

0xB0 is not a valid ASCII code. You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Any byte greater than hexadecimal 0x7F is decoded as the Unicode question mark ("?")

Answer (score 4):

That is because appearantly .NET [doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8) the [Extended ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Every value above 127 will produce `?`, which is `63`.

Hence, converting the `?` back will result in `63`.

When running the code with UTF8 encoding, you will see it goes to the extended page, since the `newBytes` in this sample returns 4 bytes instead of 2:

```
byte[] oriBytes = { 0xB0, 0x2D };
string oriInStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oriBytes);
byte[] newBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oriInStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

In you byte[] `0xB0` changes to 176 and `0x2D` change to 45. When converted from ASCII which has only 128 character 176 will give you ? (undefined) and 45 gives you -.

Try to debug the code and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

ahaah.. I got it! use `Encoding.Unicode` instead of ASCII. Beware guys... ;)

```
   byte[] oriBytes = { 0xB0, 0x2D };                         // oriBytes -> 0xB0, 0x2D
   string oriInStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(oriBytes);   // oriInStr ->   "?-"
   oriBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(oriInStr);           // oriBytes -> 0xB0, 0x2D
```

Comment: this works yes if you dont actualy want the string to be represented in ascii.

Comment: I tested it with a very long string (text), in fact copying half a page. Convert it to bytes array then back to string. I can get the original text... Just watch out about this simple mistake. It can lead to severe headache, at least for me... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned .Net doesnt support extended ascii. To solve this problem you should cast the byte values to char which is essentialy int and it will map them correctly.

```
 byte[] oriBytes = { 0xB0, 0x2D };                      
 string oriInStr = "";
 for (int a = 0; a < oriBytes.Length; a++)
     oriInStr += (char)(oriBytes[a]);
 oriBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(oriInStr);
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? It gives the very same results! 0x3F, 0x2D

Comment: i did yes how are you printing it out?